# REST url scheme

Tags: api, url, rest

I have many subsets (sorting/filtering) of images that I want to show to users.

Among them:

- List images a user owns
- List images a user likes

I want to know what's a good addressing scheme for these:

```
/image/?user_id={user_id}
/image/like/?user_id={user_id}
```

vs.

```
/image/user/{user_id}
/image/like/user/{user_id}
```

Suppose I also want to list all users who like an image:

```
/user/like/image/{image_id}
```

vs.

```
/user/?image_id={image_id}&mode=like
```

I guess I could conjure up dozen more possibilities, and I'm beginning to think: is this supposed to be hard?

Can I just settle on one scheme that makes most sense to me? Are there guide that would eliminate certain possibilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- User liking Image, here user is just a relationship/link to the Resource `Image`

hence, `/image/like/user`

In the Images like() you may want to implicitly update User resource with `/user/like/image`

The whole process can be vice versa